How do we select only particular word in bash?
I have this output from a cli -
host-0 ec: 0
    kafka_5.1.1-2_1
host-1 ec: 1
host-2 ec: 0
    kafka_5.1.1-2_0
host-3 ec: 0
host-4 ec: 0
host-5 ec: 0

I want to copy & save host-0 & host-2 which precede a kafka line.
The kafka can come under any of the hosts so I need code that will save only those with kafka in the line immediately after.
I am planning to save the output in a txt file, then read the lines & save each line in array, then go through array, find the kafka's & save the previous index value.
Is this a correct method or should I try some simpler way?

Making a few assumptions, this seems simplest and fastest.
$: awk '/^host/{host=$1} /^[[:space:]]+kafka/{print host}' data
host-0
host-2

If you are more comfortable with sed -
$: sed -En '/^host/h; /^[[:space:]]+kafka/{x; s/ .*//; p}' data
host-0
host-2

if there are repeats in the input that you don't want in the output -
$: awk '/^host/{host=$1} /^[[:space:]]+kafka/{if(!seen[host]++)print host}' data
host-0
host-2

For the record, the logic you described works fine.
$: $cli_cmd | mapfile -t data

$: for i in "${!data[@]}"; do [[ "${data[i]}" =~ ^[[:space:]]+kafka ]] && printf "%s\n" "${data[i-1]%% *}"; done
host-0
host-2


If you need kafka, search for kafka:
your_command | grep -B1 kafka


But I want the host-X where the kafka is present. Like if the Kafka is present below host-5 then I want to save host-5 in my variable.
As both are on different lines, I cannot search using kafka work

grep -B1 will also show 1 line before the match, which should be the host name.

What about this:
grep -B 1 "kafka" file1.txt | grep -v "kafka" | grep -v "\-\-" | awk -F " " '{print $1}'


grep -B 1 shows the line, before "kafka"
grep -v "kafka" hides the word "kafka"
grep -v "\-\-" hides the line separators, caused by grep -B 1.
awk -F " " '{print $1}' takes the first column

Have fun! :-)

The backslashes are superfluous; the dash does not have a special meaning. But more fundamentally, four external processes for a simple task is probably something you want to avoid, especially if one of them is already Awk. See also useless use of grep | awk

Similarly like it has already been answered, you can do:
<cli_command>  | grep -B1 "kafka" | grep "host"

And if you want to save it directly to a file, you can do it like this:
<cli_command>  | grep -B1 "kafka" | grep "host" > /path/to/my.file


This will do weird things if the kafka line also contains host.
